# Leetcode Database 584. COALESCE(referee_id,0) meaning

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried the leetcode 584 database query challenge
Here is the challenge
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhvYw.png)

The answer from a guy at forum show me the answer should be:

```
SELECT name FROM customer WHERE COALESCE(referee_id,0) <> 2;
```

I know the `COALESCE FUNCTION` is about. However, I do not know why put 0 in the parenthesis as parameter and the logic in the code `"COALESCE(referee_id,0)<>2"` 
I hope the someone can help me explain the logic at `WHERE` clause.
Thank you so much and I appreciate it.

Comment: If there is a NULL `referee_id` then the value 0 is used.

Comment: COALESCE will return the first non NULL parameter.

Comment: By having all null referee_id be 0 the WHERE condition is effectively filtering out these nulls by making 0 not equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

If `referee_id` was `NULL`, `referee_id <> 2` would also be `NULL`, so not true. `coalesce(referee_id, 0) <> 2` would be the same as `0 <> 2` when `referee_id` was `NULL` and `0 <> 2` is true.

The customers with a `referee_id` of `NULL` should be included according to the exercise. So that's why `coalesce(referee_id, 0) <> 2` is used.

I however would rather write

```
...
WHERE referee_id <> 2
       OR referee_id
...
```

because what if one wants to change the query to check for customers with a `referee_id` other than `0`. Just changing the literal would then exclude the rows with a `referee_id` of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate this as :

```
SELECT name 
FROM customer 
WHERE referee_id <> 2 or referee_id is null;
```

If you write this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM customer 
WHERE COALESCE(referee_id,2) <> 2;
```

It will return only 'Zack'.

If you write this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM customer 
WHERE COALESCE(referee_id,null, 2) <> 2;
```

You will also get only 'Zack' because the coalesce will return first value that is not null and if they are all null it will return null.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00eedfd67c6eb710b9716adb67fdc567) you can see all this 3 examples in action. Maybe it will help.